# Is it possible to interrupt Popen subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
command = "ping google.com -t"
with Popen(["cmd", "/c", command], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
           universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line.strip())
```

I am using Popen to run a command line argument and capture the output. I would like to send a keystroke to stop this depending on input from the user, but I am not sure how to interrupt the subprocess. In the above example, "Ctrl C" would be required, but in my code I just need to send the letter "q".

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `p.terminte()` and `p.kill()` works, your example is confusing though, since you are not using keystrokes as input for your program.

Comment: The executable I am running instead of "ping google" doesn't take any inputs other than as initial arguments. p.kill() and p.terminate() stop the executable, but if I send "q" in cmd when running it the executable stops itself safely (as it is connected to a device). I'm trying to wrap this in a GUI that doesn't rely on command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


command = "ping google.com -t"


while True:  # making a loop
    try:

        with Popen(["cmd", "/c", command], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
               universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line.strip())

          # used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # if key 'q' is pressed 
            print('EXIT  !')
            p.kill()
            break  # finishing the loop
    except:
        break
```